# SonarQube does not display code coverage on project homepage when scanning a branch

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, code-coverage, jacoco, pull-request

When scanning code from a pull request (bitbucket) Sonar ignores the code coverage report. This process is performed on Jenkins.
Create report command:

```
clean install -Pjacoco org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report -s 
./template_config/settings.xml
```

It's offline mode coverage scan.
Then executing scanner command:

```
sonar:sonar -Psonar -Dsonar.branch.name=${PULL_REQUEST_FROM_BRANCH} 
-Dsonar.branch.target=${PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH} -Dsonar.verbose=true
-Dsonar.inclusions=${SONAR_DIFF} -Dsonar.host.url="sonar_address"
-Dsonar.login="any_login" -s ./template_config/settings.xml
```

With sonar inclusions option:
[image: With sonar inclusions option]

All the branches in the sonar marked as long living.
In the "sonar.inclusions" option I pass a list of files that have been modified by this pull request.
If i remove the option , the coverage will be displayed in the dashboard. But the sonar scans the whole project. Please help to solve this problem.

Without sonar inclusions option:
[image: Without sonar inclusions option]

Answer (score 0):

After merging with the main branch and adding new code, I created a second pull request. The analysis job was run in Jenkins and the coverage was displayed in the dashboard.

[The resulting dashboard with "sonar.inclusions"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skFR8.png)

But one thing. Code coverage was evaluated against the code that changed in the second pull request. The code from the first pull request is not analyzed.